# Repeat command line in the output

Tags: command-line-interface

I've the necessity that the first line of any saved (redirected)  output (eg ls > output.file or fls something > output.file) is the comand itself (so to remember the given comand).
Someone can help me? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing -x to bash

For example say a file named repeat.sh has the following

```
#!/bin/bash -x
ls -ld /tmp

$ chmod 755 repeat.sh

$ ./repeat.sh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is what i was looking for